# Keyword not supported: 'data source' error occuring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, sql-server-express

Error :

> *Keyword not supported: 'data source'.
>   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)*

Connection string that I am using is

```
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Previously it was working when application deployed on servers.

But from now when I deployed on same server, I am getting error even though I am not using it. It is just declared in config file. I am using other sql connection strings in my application.

Can anybody figure out what exactly is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i edit your question so it is readable for others, y you reject ?

Comment: i have not done anything.

Comment: have you tried changing data source to Data Source

Comment: yes, I tried, but still same error.

Comment: The connection string per se looks fine - how are you accessing your data? Using "raw" ADO.NET SQL? Stored procedures? Linq-to-SQL? Entity Framework??

Comment: I am accessing data using ADO.NET SQL

Comment: Can you show us how you read and use the connection string in your application code?

Comment: I am using, connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["

Comment: And also on SIT, UAT servers it works fine, but only on Production servers it is giving error.